# jQuery Datatables losing reference on pagination

Tags: jquery, datatables

I currently have a table that is generated server side (Table A).  Clicking a row in Table A calls CreateTable(arrayData):

```
function CreateTable(arrayData){
var table = $('#tableB').DataTable({
            destroy: true,
            bFilter: false,
            bLengthChange: false,
            dt: "[-head|-body]-left",
            "data": arrayData,
            "language": {
                "paginate": {
                    "first": "First",
                    "last": "Last",
                    "next": "Next",
                    "previous": "Prev"
                }
});

$('#tableB tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    //$("#tableB tbody tr").click(function (event) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }else{
        table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
    var rowIdx = table.row(this).index();
    SetInfo(arrData[rowIdx], null);
    });
}
```

Pagination and row highlighting in **Table B** works fine when I first click on any row in **Table A**.  However when I click on another row in **Table A**, row highlights in **Table B** stop working, and `SetInfo()` is somehow called twice.  If I again select another row in **Table A**, `SetInfo()` is now called four times, then eight etc.  When I try using *(currently commented out)*:

```
$("#tableB tbody tr").click(function (event) {...}
```

Everything works as expected on page 1 of **Table B**, but not on any other pages - it doesn't seem to bind correctly.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Another example that might shed some light on the issue - I've added the following:

$('#TableB').on('draw.dt', function () {
var info = table.page.info();
console.log('Showing page: ' + (info.page + 1) + ' of ' + info.pages);
});

When I click on Table A, row 1, it creates Table B with 2 pages. Clicking on Table B page 2 outputs:

"Showing page: 2 of 2"

Next, I click on Table A, row 2, it destroys and recreates Table B with 7 pages. Clicking on Table B page 2 outputs:

"Showing page: 2 of 2"
"Showing page: 2 of 7"

Comment: Clicking on Table B page 3 outputs:

Showing page: 2 of 2"
Showing page: 3 of 7"

Clicking on Table B page 4 outputs:

"Showing page: 2 of 2"
"Showing page: 4 of 7"

Next, I click on Table A, row 1 again. It destroys and recreates Table B with 2 pages. Clicking on Table B page 2 outputs:

"Showing page: 2 of 2"
"Showing page: 4 of 7"
"Showing page: 2 of 2"

Clicking on Table B page 1 outputs:

"Showing page: 2 of 2"
"Showing page: 4 of 7"
"Showing page: 1 of 2"

It's almost as though the destroyed tables are still somewhere in the DOM.

Comment: Apologies about the formatting, I'm not sure why my post isn't picking up line breaks.

Comment: This kind of question is difficult to answer without a test case. http://jsfiddle.net/ / http://live.datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

We figured it out. We put the binding in its own method and used the callback 'drawCallback':

```
function CreateTable(arrayData){
    var table = $('#tableB').DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    bFilter: false,
    bLengthChange: false,
    dt: "[-head|-body]-left",
    "data": arrayOfData,
    "drawCallback": BindOnClick,
    "pageLength": 5,
    ....etc.
 });

function BindOnClick() {
    //get the table object:
    var table = $('#tableB').DataTable();
    //set the row highlighting:
    $("#tableB tbody tr").off("click").on("click", function () {  //.off in order to avoid multiple bindings
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
       }
       else {
        table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        }

        //now call any method you want and pass in data
        //based on row index:
        var rowIdx = table.row(this).index();
        SetInfo(table.data()[rowIdx]);
    });
 }
```

Comment: A better solution is to just wrap `#tableB` with another element (`#tableBwrapper`), and then the code in your question will work if you adjust it like this: `$('#tableBwrapper').on('click', 'tbody tr', function () {`.

Comment: I actually tried wrapping my table in a <div>.  Why would this be better?

Comment: My solution is better because the problem is being solved in the correct way, instead of having to rebind the click event every time your table changes. Also, the `drawCallback` event may be fired more often than you think, especially if you use certain features of DataTables. You will also need to make your `table` variable "global" (I can't see the rest of your code) like this: `var table; function CreateTable(arrayData){
table = ...`.

Comment: This results in SetInfo() being called multiple times per row click.

Comment: @D3v Do you know if this problem is solved in the most recent version of DataTables with state saving? I am facing a similar issue.